# No tap-to-click setting for ASUS F556 touchpad on eOS Loki

Tags: touchpad

I am having an issue with my ASUS F556U laptop touchpad - changes I make in touchpad settings have no effect, I cannot turn tap-to-click off and scrolling doesn't work, no matter what I do.
So I have tried playing with xipunt. xinput list returns:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

To me it seems that FTE1001... is my touchpad, so I tried using xinput list-props 11 to get available settings:

```
Device 'FTE1001:00 0B05:0101':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (276): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (277): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (278):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (279):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (280):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (281):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (282):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (260): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (261):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (262):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (283): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (284): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (285):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (286):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (287):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (288): 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (289): 0
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event12"
    Device Product ID (264):    2821, 257
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (290):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (265):    1
```

I have tried setting Scroll Methods Enabled to 0,0,1 too, it had no effect on scrolling (though I'm unsure about which value being what method).

What I would like is to turn tap-to-click off and get the scrolling working, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: See [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=120181).

Answer (score 0):

As the code is in 1s and 0s 1 means activated and 0 means deactivated

You need to activate natural schrolling and scroll methods and button scrolling button.

the command to turn off your touchpad in terminal is the following

xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0